# python regex in txt

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file, need to find words that are min 6 digits, have uppercase and lowercase letters, digits and punctuation marks. What is my mistake with re?

```
import re
word_list = []
with open('passwords.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        word_list += re.findall(r'^?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6}', line)
```

Comment: Missing opening parenthesis `(` after the `^`

Comment: This looks like a password validation regex though, not a word finding regex. If that's the case you should take a look at [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import re
word_list = []
with open('passwords.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        word_list += re.findall(r'[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]{6}', line)
```